# Alternative to eval() when dealing with d3 animation queues

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

I am writing an app which will run numerous small animations. Certain attributes may be animated, and others may not be, depending on their availability. However, d3 animations need to be in a queue to work, and I saw no other way than to use eval().

My code looks like this:

```
            var func = "thisClass.tagHandle.transition() \
                .duration(len).ease('linear')";
            if( typeof somevar.x !== 'undefined' ) {
                func += ".attr('cx', somevar.x)";
            }
            if( typeof somevar.y !== 'undefined' ) {
                func += ".attr('cy', somevar.y)";
            }
            if( typeof somevar.r !== 'undefined' ) {
                func += ".attr('r', somevar.r)";
            }
            if( typeof somevar.c !== 'undefined' ) {
                func += ".attr('stroke', somevar.c)";
            }
            func += ";";
            eval(func);
```

Executing each animation separately, outside the queue, makes the animations not work correctly. This function may possibly be executed quite rapidly -- I am afraid about efficiency and functionality issues when I consider putting dummy values into the animation queue, thus taking up unnecessary processing time (the application is already a bit heavy on Firefox). Yet many say that eval is evil and so forth. Is there any good alternative to this issue?

This is the first time I've ever used eval(). I don't know whether it's like an iframe -- a tool often abused, leading to an unnecessarily poor reputation -- or whether it's truly something that should be avoided like the plague.

Thank you.

Comment: If they are executed one by one anyway, is there a performance gain in using eval over `var trans = thisClass.tagHandle.transition();trans.duration(len).ease('linear');if(somevar.x || somevar.x===0) trans.attr('cx', somevar.x);if(somevar.y || somevar.y===0) trans.attr('cy', somevar.y);if(somevar.r||somevar.r===0) trans.attr('r', somevar.r)....`

Comment: Yes, there is. The animations stop working when they are taken out of the queue order, I have tried that.

Comment: Then eval seems to be a way out. As long as you know what you are doing

Comment: Can you put DEFAULT values (e.g no dummy) in the somevar.* as in `if (!somevar.c) somevar.c=0;`

Comment: No, because those data members are coordinates or colours or things like that. So a value of 0 would mess the animation up, while a value of null would make d3 explode. Unless I had missed some obvious thing...

Edit: one thing I considered was recalling the last values of those data members. If there were no new data members this iteration, then the ones from the last iteration must not have changed. However, once again, I feel like it would be a waste of resources to run blank d3 animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating multiple transitions on the same object cancels the other ones out, but adding new attribute or style statements to the same transition isn't a problem.  You just have to save the transition in a variable.

```
var activeTransition = thisClass.tagHandle.transition() 
            .duration(len).ease('linear');

if( typeof somevar.x !== 'undefined' ) {
    activeTransition.attr('cx', somevar.x);
}
if( typeof somevar.y !== 'undefined' ) {
    activeTransition.attr('cy', somevar.y);
}
if( typeof somevar.r !== 'undefined' ) {
    activeTransition.attr('r', somevar.r);
}
if( typeof somevar.c !== 'undefined' ) {
    activeTransition.attr('stroke', somevar.c);
}
```